# How to submit a GET Form to a Parameter-based page?

Tags: php, forms, parameters, get, submit

I have a site where each page is actually a parameter of the index.php page.

So the `search` page is simply:  `www.mysite.com/?p=search`

I created a GET form whose action is the page above (`http://www.mysite.com/?p=search`).  However, when I submit the form, it is actually submitting the GET parameters to `www.mysite.com/index.php` instead of `www.mysite.com/?p=search`.

How do I get the form to actually submit to `www.mysite.com/?p=search` so that I end up with something like:

```
www.mysite.com/?p=search&param1=blah1&param2=blah2@&param3=blah3
```

instead of:

```
www.mysite.com/index.php?param1=blah1&param2=blah2@&param3=blah3
```

?

Comment: You could add an `<input type="hidden" name="p" value="search">` to your form

Comment: You must to redirect via .htacesss

see this: [htaccess][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10758138/htaccess-rewrite-querystring-and-remove-empty-value/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't use a form to make a GET request to a URI with a query string in the action without destroying the existing query string. Use a hidden input instead.

Add `<input type="hidden" name="p" value="search">` to your form and set `action="/"`